# SSMS and SSDT requires administrator

Tags: uac, windows-server-2012-r2, ssms, sql-server-2012

I connect to a client's Server (Server 2012R2) via RDP.

I always get the UAC prompt when I start the SQL tools, managemant studio (SSMS) and data tools (SSDT). If I press cancel in the UAC dialog the program does not start.

Other tools like the Sql server profiler, notepad etc does not trigger UAC.

It is not really a big issue since I am administrator but why is elevated rights neccessary? The same tools work fine on my machine with a standard user.

Comment: It's possible that windows 2008 isn't passing all your group memberships to SSMS when you open the application. If you press cancel and then take a look at the security section in the event log, what's the error message?

Comment: What kind of group membership is required to start SSMS and SSDT but not the profiler? The error message is: "The user account is in a different forest than the computer account. The processing of Group Policy from another forest is not allowed. Group Policy will be processed using Loopback Replace mode. The scope of the user policy settings will be determined by the location of the computer object in Active Directory. The settings will be acquired from the User Configuration of these policies."